# Is it possible to exclude parts of your model using Html.EditorFor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Should be pretty simple question here.  I have

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Training)
```

I dont want to show some parts.  Is there a way for me to exclude some from showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
```

That should do the trick!